# I'm currently working with graph plotting in manim, and I wanted to ask how is a graph plotted in manim?

Tags: python-3.x, manim

I am working in manim, plotting graphs. I wanted to ask what is the interval in which manim code plots graphs?

When I write the code `grid.plot(lambda x: #function of x)` then what is the algorithm for plotting this function?

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted the algorithm as solving the function of x at a range of points, and interpolating the difference between them. There are various parameters each function takes in:

Parameters

- Function - The function to be plotted in the form of `(lambda x: x**2)`
- t_range - Determines the length that the function spans. By default `[0, 1]`
- scaling - A class applied to the points of the function.
- use_smoothing - Whether to interpolate between the points of the function after they have been created. (Will have odd behaviour with a low number of points)
- use_vectorized - Whether to pass in the generated t value array to the function as `[t_0, t_1, ...]`. Only use this if your function supports it. Output should be a numpy array of shape `[[x_0, x_1, ...], [y_0, y_1, ...], [z_0, z_1, ...]]` but `z` can also be 0 if the Axes is 2D
- discontinuities - Values of t at which the function experiences discontinuity.
- dt - The left and right tolerance for the discontinuities.

A little code snippet from the [source code](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/blob/main/manim/mobject/graphing/functions.py)

```
def generate_points(self):
    p_min, p_max = (
        np.array([self.x_range[0], self.y_range[0]]),
        np.array([self.x_range[1], self.y_range[1]]),
    )
    curves = plot_isoline(
        fn=lambda u: self.function(u[0], u[1]),
        pmin=p_min,
        pmax=p_max,
        min_depth=self.min_depth,
        max_quads=self.max_quads,
    )  # returns a list of lists of 2D points
    curves = [
        np.pad(curve, [(0, 0), (0, 1)]) for curve in curves if curve != []
    ]  # add z coord as 0
    for curve in curves:
        self.start_new_path(curve[0])
        self.add_points_as_corners(curve[1:])
    if self.use_smoothing:
        self.make_smooth()
    return self
```

I am no manim expert, I'm sure others can explain it better, but I hope this helps answer your question.